# Why does my recursive solution to pruning binary tree not work?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

Link to question: https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-pruning/

Basically, given the root of a binary tree, return the same tree where every subtree (of the given tree) not containing a 1 has been removed.

My code:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* pruneTree(TreeNode* root) {
        recurse(root);
        return root;
    }
    
    bool recurse(TreeNode* &root) {
        if (root == nullptr)
            return false;
        cout<<"val: "<<root->val<<" ";

        if (recurse(root->left) == false && recurse(root->right) == false && root->val==0)
        {
            root = nullptr;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
};
```

Using the print statements, I found out that after finding one node to remove, it removes it and then just stops recursing and returns the tree. Why does it do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (  ... )
```

In order for this `if` statement to evaluate to `true`, both of the recursive calls in the `if` statement must return false. This `if` statement uses the boolean `&&` operator. In C++, the boolean `&&` operator requires both its left-hand and right-hand side expressions to be true which in this case will happen only if the recursive calls return `false`. If any of the recursive calls return `true` it becomes logically impossible for this `if` statement to evaluate to `true`.

The very next statement, when `if` statement is `false`, is:

```
 return true;
```

Therefore, as soon as the first `return` from the recursive call returns `true`, for any reason, all recursive calls in progress must result in the calling `if` statements to end up with the `if` statements evaluating to `false`, and the corresponding recursive calls to `return true;` as well.

Game over.